# TypeError: iteration over non-sequence in Python

Tags: python, sumo

I have a code that uses functions to calculate the closest edge of a station id based on its geographical coordinates.

The output is a line like this (format xml):

```
  <edge id="4260662#2" from="1977648762" to="2600872721"/>
```

I need to extract only the id value from this line which is in this example: **4260662#2**, so I tried to use for loop, I put the line in a string named "ch" but when I did "for i in ch:" , it shows me an error:  **TypeError: iteration over non-sequence**.

I tried many solutions but they did not work, can you help me please?[image]

Comment: Please paste the *all* relevant parts of your code as *text*, not as an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. About your code, it seems that, contrary to what you seem to think, closestEdge isn't a string, but probably some object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closestEdge` is an instance of the [`sumolib.net.edge.Edge`](https://github.com/planetsumo/sumo/blob/ab65ad20a110c48d500aed65f5c0c100c30528f4/sumo/tools/sumolib/net/edge.py) class. It is not a string and can not be treated as such by, for example, iterating over it.

Fortunately the `Edge` class contains a method, [`getID()`](https://github.com/planetsumo/sumo/blob/ab65ad20a110c48d500aed65f5c0c100c30528f4/sumo/tools/sumolib/net/edge.py#L92), which can be used to access the id:

```
distancesAndEdges = sorted([(dist, edge) for edge, dist in edges])
dist, closestEdge = distancesAndEdges[0]

print(closestEdge.getID())
```

On a related note, you do not need to sort the list of edges to find the closest (that with minimum distance). Instead you can use the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) builtin function with the `key` argument:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dist, closestEdge = min(edges, key=itemgetter(1))
print(closestEdge.getID())
```

Not only is this code more readable, but `min()` has time complexity *O(n)*, which is faster than *O(n log n)* for `sorted()`.